# Mobile Push QUESTION - Contact Key

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilesdk, sfdcmobilesdk-android

My DEV app team is making a change to the app so that unknown contacts will not be included in MC's all contact. This is done via the function `setDelayRegistrationUntilContactKeyIsSet(true)`.
How can it then be tested in MC that the change was successful? Thus:

1. how do I check that unknown contacts do not enter MC?
2. how do I check that contacts with contactID have entered correctly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's actually a pretty simple trick to check what you're asking. Setup an addressee list using the `lastModifiedDate` property in `MobilePush Demographics` with a value of {today's date}.

Do a fresh installation without setting a `contactKey`. Do another and set the `contactKey`. Your list will contain only the device with the key set.

I can assure you, however, that this feature works as expected :)